where to call another macro within my code and how to complete the sub
re: this link Open an Access database and run one of its Macros from Excel
I am using the code within a seperate macro on my excel worksheet.
Macro1 runs a series of steps on the worksheet from a button, it is the only and active worksheet within the workbook
once cells are copied using Call macro2 my results appear in my Access table but are not saved. More importantly Macro2 tries to run again instead of resuming Macro1 and stops here even though my code reads
OpenCurrentDatabase.dbpath 
(which is declared in a string using appAccess within Macro2 which is located in Access to allow writes to a query)

appAccess.DoCmd.RunMacro.macroName 
(declared above, and completes the data is written to the tables in the query)

appAccess.CloseCurrentDatabase acSaveYes 
(the values are in the Access table at this point)

set appAccess = Nothing

End Sub (it's a public Sub)

and I get error 450 and it stops. OpenCurrentDatabase.dbpath
I run Macro2 from Macro1 after some values are copied via Macro2 (Access macro)
so that code is
ActiveWorkBook.Save

   Call ExportMacro (this is Macro2 located in Access being called from this Macro in Excel)

Range(A1:A18").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
ActiveWorkBook.Save

End Sub

I would like Macro1 to continue after Macro2 runs. I think I need help :)

ExportMacro is code in Access? Is it a macro or VBA?

Macro1 and Macro2 are actual names of macros?

Use application.Run method to execute a VBA procedure in Access; application.DoCmd.RunMacro to execute a macro.

hello again June7! Macro1 is named Clean and Macro2 is named Export. I have progressed so that running the Macr2 (export) is actually a macro located in access. So Macro1 Clean cleans up my test results and Macro2 export is locted in access and can be run after each run of Macro 1, but ultimately I would like to Loop this so that all results are inserted into my access table

as a check on macro1 I inserted a cell C1 which checks if c1.value = "" then exit sub, end if, that part works. Im just not sure how to tell excel to run my Export (Macro2) after each run of Clean (macro1) then check cell c1

I don't do much coding behind Excel and there is not enough of your code posted for me to really understand what you are trying to accomplish. Exactly what is the confusion? Why can't you call Macro2 from the same procedure that calls Macro1? Consider posting in a forum that allows attaching files and provide yours for analysis.
